# Cannot set table cell background properly

Tags: html, css

```css
.pointy {
  background-image: url('img/Header.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top: 100px">
  <table style="float: left;">
    <tr class="pointy">
      <td>TITLE</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="float: left;">
    <tr class="pointy">
      <td>TITLE</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="float: left;">
    <tr class="pointy">
      <td>TITLE</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I am trying to add the image as a background and achieve the design as in the image below.

[My Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYgFe.png)

But sadly I couldn't get it work. This is my result right now.

[Actual Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WL3TL.png)

P.S Orange background is added just to see it clearly.

Comment: ?? you should also look for basic tutorials on how to build a table,  If table is not needed, then display does great things nowdays. 3 tags for a title ? really ? Do you know about hx tags ? If you want a table no matter, then you have th ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative option would be to create the effect using only CSS... This is useful if you want animations or hover effects for example.

```css
.pointy {
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.pointy td {
  position: relative;
}

.pointy td::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
  border-bottom: solid 20px #000;
  border-left: solid 20px transparent;
  border-right: solid 20px transparent;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top: 100px">
  <table style="float: left;">
    <tr class="pointy">
      <td>TITLE</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="float: left;">
    <tr class="pointy">
      <td>TITLE</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="float: left;">
    <tr class="pointy">
      <td>TITLE</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I might need to read thru again to understand the code but this works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your background is bigger than the cell. To center the background image, you have to add `background-position:center` to class `.pointy`. See the following example:

```css
.pointy {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/200x40');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position:center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  height:40px;
  background-color: orange;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top: 100px">
  <table style="float: left;">
      <tr class="pointy">
          <td>TITLE</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="float: left;">
      <tr class="pointy">
          <td>TITLE</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="float: left;">
      <tr class="pointy">
          <td>TITLE</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

You can optimize your table structure. So you can also use the following example:

```css
table {
  margin-top:100px;
}
thead th {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/200x40');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position:center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  height:40px;
  background-color: orange;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>TITLE</th>
    <th>TITLE</th>
    <th>TITLE</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>CONTENT</td>
      <td>CONTENT</td>
      <td>CONTENT</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to add

```
background-position:center;
```

and change

```
background-size: cover;
```

to

```
background-size: contain;
or
background-size: 100%;
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use background-position

Answer (score 0):

It seems the background is bigger than your cell.

You can try using `background-size` as described here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

probably setting it to 'contain' will give you the closes result:

> contain
>
> A keyword that scales the image as large as possible and maintains image aspect ratio (image doesn't get squished). Image is letterboxed within the container. When the image and container have different dimensions, the empty areas (either top/bottom of left/right) are filled with the background-color.

In general you need to make sure the cell dimensions (width/hight) match the image exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `background-position:center` and **adjust some padding of the td** **can do the trick**.

> Here is the working code:

```css
table {
  width: 33%;
}

.pointy {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQISJ.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-position: center;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.pointy td {
  padding: 18px 0 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top: 100px">
  <table style="float: left;">
    <tr class="pointy">
      <td>TITLE</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="float: left;">
    <tr class="pointy">
      <td>TITLE</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="float: left;">
    <tr class="pointy">
      <td>TITLE</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For infos, an example with a better use of html tags (`hx` or `th` ) or CSS displays (`inline-block`,`flex` or `grid` )

```css
h2,
th {
  font-size: 30px;
}
.ib {white-space:nowrap;}/* keep a single line*/
.ib h2 {
  display: inline-block;
}


table {
  border-spacing: 4px 0
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex h2 {
  margin: 0 2px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 235px);
  grid-gap: 4px;
  min-width:800px;
}

/* bg it is about background-size. image missing replaced with average gradient*/

.title {
  padding: 1.5em 3em 0.5em;
  color: white;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 1em, black 1em), linear-gradient(45deg, black 44%, transparent 45%) right top no-repeat, linear-gradient(-45deg, black 44%, transparent 45%) left top no-repeat;
  background-size: auto, 50% 100%, 50% 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>header + h2 inline-block; </h1>
<header class="ib">
  <h2 class="title">title</h2>
  <h2 class="title">title</h2>
  <h2 class="title">title</h2>
</header>
<h1>table header, th </h1>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="title"> title</th>
      <th class="title"> title</th>
      <th class="title"> title</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<h1>header + h2 and flex </h1>
<header class="flex">
  <h2 class="title">title</h2>
  <h2 class="title">title</h2>
  <h2 class="title">title</h2>
</header>

<h1>header + h2 and grid </h1>
<header class="grid">
  <h2 class="title">title</h2>
  <h2 class="title">title</h2>
  <h2 class="title">title</h2>
</header>
```